# CSS file only partially works with Google App Engine

Tags: html, css, google-app-engine

I want to add some style to the HTML part of a simple web app that I created using Google App Engine while taking Udacity's Web Development course. However, the CSS file that I added seems to only partially apply to the page. Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../static/main.css" />
    <title>What do ya wanna do?</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="wrapper">
        <a value="birth" class="myButton">Mystify your text!</a>
        <a value="rot13" class="myButton">Enter your birthday</a>
        <a value="signup" class="myButton">Feel like signing up?</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS file (I don't have much skills in CSS, so I created this using http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/):

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -10px;

.myButton {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:21px 45px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.myButton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0);
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

And finally, here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
application: appudacityhelloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: hello.application

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

The only part of CSS that seems to work is the place of the `<form>`. I have my HTML codes in `/templates` folder and my CSS in `/static` folder and everything looks exactly like another app that I have developed except the contents of the CSS file. I have tried everything and I am starting to think that maybe GAE has some limitations in dealing with CSS. Am I missing something or is that the case?

Comment: It looks like JoeBiz found the problem. I will just add that a CSS file cannot "partially apply" - it is either loaded by a browser, or it is not. If some rules are ignored, there is a problem somewhere in the CSS file.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I spent half a day on this and couldn't figure it out. 
The way I was trying to debug it was to put these files in a separate folder and open them using Chrome, and it was working exactly as expected. So I guess probably Chrome has a way of detecting and correcting these kinds of problems which made me think the problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a curly brace at the end of the .wrapper css rule.

Change:

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
```

to:

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

and everything applies.